# Correct indentation for ordered list with equation and second paragraph in markdown?

Tags: markdown, r-markdown

I would like to use an ordered list in R Markdown that includes (1) a formula and (2) a second paragraph indented correctly (i.e., aligned with the rest of the ordered list). Without a formula, R Markdown recognizes extra spaces before the second paragraph and indents correctly:

1. **First item**
   Here is the first paragraph.

   Here is the second paragraph, properly indented

However, when an equation is included, the second paragraph is no longer indented correctly with the rest of the ordered list. See the code and rendered Markdown in the chunk and output below.

```
1. **First item**  
Here is a relevant formula: 

$$f_{sc} =  \dfrac{e_s}{\textrm{int } ((e_s - 1)/40) + 1}$$  

  In R, write a function for this Formula (1)

2. **Second item**
```

1. **First item**
   Here is a relevant formula:

$$f_{sc} =  \dfrac{e_s}{\textrm{int } ((e_s - 1)/40) + 1}$$

In R, write a function for this Formula (1)

2. **Second item**

Is there a way to format an ordered list in Markdown / R Markdown with an equation, a second paragraph and proper indentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave blank lines between paragraphs and indent lines that should be included in a list item by four spaces or one tab:

```
1. **First item**

    Here is a relevant formula: 

    $$f_{sc} =  \dfrac{e_s}{\textrm{int } ((e_s - 1)/40) + 1}$$  

    In R, write a function for this Formula (1)

2. **Second item**
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the indentation of the equation too?