# R Markdown and list formatting - continued text is not indented?

Tags: r, formatting, r-markdown

In an R markdown file, I have a list that looks like this:

1. Item 1 discussion
2. Item 2 discussion

```
\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}
```

continued discussion of item 2.
3. Item 3 discussion

The continued discussion of item 2 (after the equation) is not indented like it's part of the numbered text above it - how do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct indentation for ordered list with equation and second paragraph in markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459816/correct-indentation-for-ordered-list-with-equation-and-second-paragraph-in-markd)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that works taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126727/indent-without-adding-a-bullet-point-or-number-in-rmarkdown-output-to-pdf):

1. Item 1 discussion
2. Item 2 discussion

```
\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}
```

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[] continued discussion of item 2.
\end{itemize}
```

3. Item 3 discussion